# Show user statistics using Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, express, mean-stack

I am building a web platform using the MEAN stack intended to be used by different business in the same field. I want to be able to show the businesses using my platform statistics about who visited their pages, how many bookings were made through the website.. etc.

I know of tools such as Facebook or Google Analytics that can collect statistics about my web application. Is it a good idea to use these tools and then query them to display customized statistics to each user? Or are there other better alternatives? I'm using AngularJS 1 for front-end.

I am a beginner so detailed advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be specific about exactly what statistics you need to collect.  What you mentioned seemed to be stats that are application specific. Google Analytics is not appropriate for that.

We are not supposed to recommend tools on Stack Overflow because that is completely subjective.  However, I will say that one very popular tool for collecting stats in Node is `statsd`.

But basically I think you should make sure your requirements are clear and then tailor a solution for that, rather than trying to select a tool first.